# In XSLT, how do I access the attribute values of two sibling nodes at once (while accessing node a, I need to access node b)?

Tags: xml, xslt

How do I print out the attribute values of all message and lifeline nodes at once?
By "at once", I mean while printing out a message name,  I need to access the lifeline nodes.  The only attributes I am concerned about are: lifeline/@name, and message/@name.   I am trying to print out the message names, with the lifeline name that the message moves from.  You do not have to post an answer to solve how I will associate the message with its start and end lifelines.  That's tricky.  I just need to know how to access the lifeline and message attribute values at once.  Or if its even possible.  The XSLT shows the output format.

For the following XML , just focus on the lifeline, message, and packagedElement nodes.  For context, the XML is of a UML model with a sequence diagram.  Preserving the order of the sequence messages is not necessary.  I am developing on the client side, thus the stylesheet href line is included in the XML.  I can't change the XML beyond the stylesheet href.  All of the needed namespaces are included.  I am transforming XML to text.  I want to print out these values as tab delimited text.

XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet href="multiple nonthreaded iers.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
 <uml:Model xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI"  xmlns:ecore="http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" xmlns:uml="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/3.0.0/UML" xmi:id="idModel" name="main">
  <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Package" xmi:id="idPackage" name="ThreadedIERPackage">
    <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Collaboration" xmi:id="idCollaboration" name="ThreadedIERCollaboration">
      <ownedBehavior xmi:type="uml:Interaction" xmi:id="idInteraction">
        <lifeline xmi:type="uml:Lifeline" xmi:id="_OccJQguaEeGMo_zLRqy_vg" name="Lifeline1"/>
        <lifeline xmi:type="uml:Lifeline" xmi:id="_Oo87QguaEeGMo_zLRqy_vg" name="Lifeline2" coveredBy="_QrWQ2AuaEeGMo_zLRqy_vg _R4-hlQuaEeGMo_zLRqy_vg _QrWQ0guaEeGMo_zLRqy_vg"/><!-- can ignore the last id -->
        <fragment xmi:type="uml:MessageOccurrenceSpecification" xmi:id="_R4-hlQuaEeGMo_zLRqy_vg" name="MessageOccurrenceSpecification2" covered="_Oo87QguaEeGMo_zLRqy_vg" event="_R4-hlguaEeGMo_zLRqy_vg" message="_R4-hlwuaEeGMo_zLRqy_vg"/>
        <fragment xmi:type="uml:MessageOccurrenceSpecification" xmi:id="_QrWQ2AuaEeGMo_zLRqy_vg" name="MessageOccurrenceSpecification1" covered="_Oo87QguaEeGMo_zLRqy_vg" event="_QrWQ2QuaEeGMo_zLRqy_vg" message="_QrWQ2guaEeGMo_zLRqy_vg"/>
        <fragment xmi:type="uml:BehaviorExecutionSpecification" xmi:id="_QrWQ0guaEeGMo_zLRqy_vg" name="BehaviorExecutionSpecification1" covered="_Oo87QguaEeGMo_zLRqy_vg" start="_QrWQ2AuaEeGMo_zLRqy_vg" finish="_R4-hlQuaEeGMo_zLRqy_vg"/>
        <message xmi:type="uml:Message" xmi:id="_QrWQ2guaEeGMo_zLRqy_vg" name="Message1" receiveEvent="_QrWQ2AuaEeGMo_zLRqy_vg"/>
        <message xmi:type="uml:Message" xmi:id="_R4-hlwuaEeGMo_zLRqy_vg" name="Message2" messageSort="reply" sendEvent="_R4-hlQuaEeGMo_zLRqy_vg"/>
      </ownedBehavior>
    </packagedElement>
    <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:CallEvent" xmi:id="_QrWQ2QuaEeGMo_zLRqy_vg" name="CallEvent1"/>
    <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:CallEvent" xmi:id="_R4-hlguaEeGMo_zLRqy_vg" name="CallEvent2"/>
  </packagedElement>
  <profileApplication xmi:type="uml:ProfileApplication" xmi:id="idProfileApplication">
    <eAnnotations xmi:type="ecore:EAnnotation" xmi:id="idProfileAnnotation" source="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/2.0.0/UML">
      <references xmi:type="ecore:EPackage" href="pathmap://SysMLActivityExtensionsProfile.uml#ProfileContentId"/>
    </eAnnotations>
    <appliedProfile xmi:type="uml:Profile" href="pathmap://SysMLActivityExtensionsProfile.uml#ActivityProfileId"/>
  </profileApplication>
</uml:Model>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:text>#Sending Lifeline (Producer)</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="$tab"/>

<xsl:text>Receiving Lifeline (Consumers)</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="$tab"/>

<xsl:text>Name(s)</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="$tab"/>
<xsl:text>ID</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$tab"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
<xsl:apply-templates />

</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="packagedElement/ownedBehavior"> 
<xsl:for-each select="lifeline"><!-- prints all lifelines-->
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/><xsl:text>.OE</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$tab"/>
</xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:text>OE --> OE</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$tab"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="message/@name"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$tab"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I have tried:
I have created a packagedElement/ownedBehavior template to access both nodes (lifeline, message), since they're both children.  However, it doesn't print out all of the messages or lifelines unless I use a for -each.  But, if I use a for-each, then I can only access messages or lifelines, not both.

I have tried using multiple templates, i.e. one for lifeline, and another for message.  Example: `<xsl:template match="lifeline">`.  Of course, I can't access both nodes' attributes at once.  Even, if I use the call template function. I have tried it and it failed.

This is a tricky one, so I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, use the union operator -- `|` -- to select both types of elements in one template:

```
<xsl:template match="lifeline|message">
```

Or:

```
<xsl:template match="packagedElement/ownedBehavior"> 
    <xsl:for-each select="lifeline|message">
        <!-- code here -->
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively, iterate over one or the other, associating as you go. Example:

```
<xsl:template match="packagedElement/ownedBehavior"> 
    <xsl:for-each select="lifeline">
        <xsl:value-of select="../message[<some_condition_here>]"/>
        <!-- code here -->
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

...where `<some_condition_here>` is a predicate selecting the associated node.

Answer (score 2):

While `for-each`ing over `lifeline` element you could use `../message` for all messages of the same `ownedBehavior`. Not sure which one you should select, the same position maybe?

Comment: Yes, I was adding this to my answer as you posted. This is probably what's needed.